# Shell script to wait for the prompt and pass user input

Tags: bash, shell

I need help in writing shell script. I am running one command which will ask for Username:, Email address:, Password:, Password (again):.

I need to write script which wait for prompt and feed the input to command. I tried with expect & send but seems not working.

```
[root@ip-1xx-xx-x-xx hue]$ sudo build/env/bin/hue  createsuperuser
Username: xyz 
Email address: xyz@xyx.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
Superuser created successfully.`
```

==============

Tried with below script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
  
cd /usr/lib/hue/
set timeout -1

sudo build/env/bin/hue createsuperuser

expect "Username: "
send -- "admin"

expect "Email address: "
send -- "admin@abc.com"

expect "Password: "
send -- "Password@123"

expect "Password (again): "
send -- "Password@123"

expect eof
```

The above script stuck at username

```
[root@ip-1xx-xx-x-xx ~]$ sh -x hueuser.sh 
+ cd /usr/lib/hue/
+ set timeout -1
+ sudo build/env/bin/hue createsuperuser
Username:
```

Comment: Could you add information about why you conclude that "it is not working"? We were not with you when "it was not working", therefore only you know what happened.

Comment: Linux uses linefeed (`\n`) as newline character, instead you are expecting a carriage return (`\r`). Usually text is enough for expect, no need to include the newline.

Comment: In addition, your screen shot shows that there is *neither* a newline nor a carriage return after the colon, but merely a space. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @tripleee, removed as suggested but didn't work and stuck at same point.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the createsuperuser command asks for `Username (leave blank to use ‘root’)`, not `Username`

Try using:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
 
cd /usr/lib/hue/ 
set timeout -1
 
sudo build/env/bin/hue createsuperuser
 
expect "Username (leave blank to use ‘root’)"
send -- "admin"
 
expect "Email address:" 
send -- "admin@abc.com"

expect "Password:"
send -- "Password@123"

expect "Password (again):" 
send -- "Password@123"

expect eof
```

Comment: Requirement is to not take any input from user. Command will run through script and should feed all the required input.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. What happens when you run your script?

Comment: It stuck at username 
[root@ip-1xx-xx-x-xx ~]$ sh -x adduser.sh 
+ cd /usr/lib/hue/
+ set timeout -1
+ sudo build/env/bin/hue createsuperuser
Username:

Comment: "Username (leave blank to use ‘root’)", it will ask when you create first user, I have user already, need to create another super user through script.

Answer (score 0):

Your `expect` script has a few problems still (even after you edited to remove the `\r`s in the `expect` strings which were also wrong).

First, you will need to `spawn` the command you are trying to run. If `sudo` works at all here, it will create a subprocess which runs outside of the control of `expect`.

Second, you need to send exactly the string you want to send, including the final newline. This is where `\r` is useful and necessary.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
  
cd /usr/lib/hue/
set timeout -1

spawn sudo build/env/bin/hue createsuperuser

expect "Username: "
send -- "admin\r"

expect "Email address: "
send -- "admin@abc.com\r"

expect "Password: "
send -- "Password@123\r"

expect "Password (again): "
send -- "Password@213\r"

expect eof
```

A much better fix if you have control over the `createsuperuser` script is to change it so it doesn't require interactive I/O. See for example how the `adduser` command on Debian-based platforms wraps the lower-level `useradd` to allow it to be called from scripts with all the necessary arguments as command-line arguments. Also, [`man newusers`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/newusers.8.html) for inspiration.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/8aa24a89648ab7c079cbce7369481fefbc05efc7/desktop/core/ext-py/Django-1.11.29/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py it appears that you can provide the arguments as options, but not sure if this is the one you are trying to use.